# Deserialize JSON property name with @ sign

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have json that is formatted the following way:

```
{
   "@start":"0",
   "@totalRecords":"1",
   "@queryTime":"0"
}
```

My class looks like the following:

```
public class SearchResult
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@start")]
        public string Start { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@totalRecords")]
        public string Total { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@queryTime")]
        public string QueryTime { get; set; }
    }
```

But Start, Total and QueryTime remain null.

Just as a reference, the deserialization is done the following way:

```
SearchResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResult>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Please show how you are doing the deserialization. You can always serialize the class with the desired values to see the correct json output though....

Comment: Serialization is done through JSON.net.

Comment: So just try `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchResultInstance);` with a instance of your `SearchResult` class with your desired values for start, totalRecords and queryTime to see the correct JSON output and try to deserialize that

Comment: Gives me the following: `json = "{\"@start\":null,\"@totalRecords\":null,\"@queryTime\":null}"`

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code and i get the desired result. 
Version of Json.Net was 4.5.10.15407.

```
string jsonString = @"{ ""@start"":""0"", ""@totalRecords"":""1"", ""@queryTime"":""0"" }";
SearchResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResult>(jsonString);
```

Check if theres a problem in the input json string (quoting, encoding or whatsoever) or if maybe its a bug in the version of Json.Net you use.

Comment: Just tried the same thing, works for me too. Got the latest Json.Net from http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/106328

Comment: I'll try with the latest version soon.